# Expression encoder cuts ending part of livejob webcam recording/encoding

Tags: expression-encoder-sdk

I am using expression encoder 4 SP2 SDK in C#, as I found, it can record and encode cameras live. So I managed to write some code, which works fine, when computer is good enough. Then the recorded video is fine.

I assumed, that when computer is slow, it will just "lag" more, skip frames etc. which wouldn't be that much of a problem in my application, but when I click button with this code:

```
liveJob.StopEncoding();
```

It stops encoding, which is great, but doesn't finish the whole video, so end part is missing. As there is no liveJob.Pause() or something like that, I don't know how to stop my camera properly to finish encoding. So I am seeking for help there.

If there is no solution, could you recommend me something similar, with very easy .net SDK, preferably stripped of any directshow graphs, easy listing of devices, simultaneous audio encoding.
(I have already looked at DirectShow .net and EmguCV)

Thanks